# Lightbox Javascript Captions

Tags: javascript, lightbox, caption

I am having an issue with my lightbox captions. I would like to use my current javascript lightbox to have captions. If you need a preview you can go to my site at [maialedesigns.com](http://maialedesigns.com). I have it up and running but I can't figure out how to get my captions in there. I have my lightbox set up to where it is basically a slideshow. I just need to have captions under each image that shows up. I have created two classes in my CSS to account for what I need (One side is going to have titles and the other a description of the work). Also, this would just be a bonus, but how could I get arrow key functionality in my lightbox?

Current Javascript for the lightbox:

```
function lightbox(e, event){
    if($(event.target).get(0).tagName == "A"){
        return;
    }
    var ww = $(window).width();
    var wh = $(window).height();


    var img = new Image();
    var clickedImage = e.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    currentArray = $(clickedImage).attr("alt") //Not defined using var so the variable would be global
    img.src = $(clickedImage).attr("src");

    var iw = img.width;
    var ih = img.height;

    var maxHeight = wh * 0.85;
    var targetWidth = ww * 0.75;
    var targetHeight = (targetWidth / iw) * ih;

    if(targetHeight > maxHeight){
        for(i=targetHeight; i > maxHeight; i = i - 20){
            targetHeight = i;
        }
        targetWidth = (targetHeight / ih) * iw;

    }

    $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", img.src);
    $("#lightbox").css("display", "block");
    $("#lightboxOverlay").css("display", "block");


    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#lightbox").css("opacity", 1);
        $("#lightboxOverlay").css("opacity", 1)
    }, 1)
}

function closeLightbox(){
    $("#lightbox").css("opacity", 0);
    $("#lightboxOverlay").css("opacity", 0)
    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#lightbox").css("display", "none");
        $("#lightboxOverlay").css("display", "none");
    }, 1000)
}

function nextSlide(direction){
    var oneArray = [
        //This is the first array
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/websites.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/website/home_desktop.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/website/funfacts_desktop.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/website/home_mobile.png",
            caption: ""

        }
    ];
    var twoArray = [
        //This is the second array
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/illustrations.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration2.jpg",
            caption: "Test 1"
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration3.jpg",
            caption: "Test 2"
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration7.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration8.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration4.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Illustrations/illustration6.png",
            caption: ""
        }
    ];
    var threeArray = [
        //This is the third array
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/images/Photography.png",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night1.jpg",
            caption: "Night Photography"
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night2.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night3.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night4.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night5.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night6.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/night7.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/genre1.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/genre2.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/genre3.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/genre4.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/genre5.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/portrait1.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/portrait2.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },
        {
            path: "http://maialedesigns.com/Photographs/portrait3.jpg",
            caption: ""
        },  
    ];

    var currentImage = $("#lightboxImage").attr("src");

    if(currentArray == "Websites"){
        for(n = 0; n < oneArray.length; n++){
            if(oneArray[n].path == currentImage){
                if(direction =="right") {
                    if(currentImage == oneArray[oneArray.length-1].path){
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", oneArray[0].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = oneArray[0].caption;
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", oneArray[n+1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = oneArray[n+1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(direction =="left") {
                    if(currentImage == oneArray[0].path){
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", oneArray[oneArray.length-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = oneArray[oneArray.length-1].caption;
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", oneArray[n-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = oneArray[n-1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    else if(currentArray == "Illustrations"){
        for(n = 0; n < twoArray.length; n++){
            if(twoArray[n].path == currentImage){
                if(direction =="right") {
                    if(currentImage == twoArray[twoArray.length-1].path){
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", twoArray[0].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = twoArray[0].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", twoArray[n+1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = twoArray[n+1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(direction =="left") {
                    if(currentImage == twoArray[0].path){
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", twoArray[twoArray.length-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = twoArray[oneArray.length-1].caption;
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", twoArray[n-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = twoArray[n-1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else if(currentArray == "Photography"){
        for(n = 0; n < threeArray.length; n++){
            if(threeArray[n].path == currentImage){
                if(direction =="right") {
                    if(currentImage == threeArray[threeArray.length-1].path){
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", threeArray[0].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = threeArray[0].caption;
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", threeArray[n+1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = threeArray[n+1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(direction =="left") {
                    if(currentImage == threeArray[0].path){
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", threeArray[threeArray.length-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = threeArray[oneArray.length-1].caption;
                        //If true, the currently displayed image is the last of the array
                        //Restart cycle to beginning
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#lightboxImage").attr("src", threeArray[n-1].path);
                        $("#lgihtboxCaption").html = threeArray[n-1].caption;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var arrayCaption = [
        {src: "John", caption: "Smith"},
        {src: "Tyler", caption: "Smith"}
]
}
```

Comment: There is no much use of captions, images and description in Javascript - you should put projects in an unordered list in HTML (or using blocks with headers and paragraphs). There, for each project, you should add title, description, data-attributes for big-image-url, etc. Than it will be easier to build your lightbox, too.

Comment: But those images are a gallery, I could not figure out a way to just do it with HTML CSS where I could just store the images in a lightbox, like a gallery.

Comment: I'm telling you to put thumbnails and everything you need for gallery in HTML, than to use Javascript to popup lightbox.